# How can I explicitly force SendMail to not use SSLv3 for STARTTLS connections?

Tags: email-server, sendmail, starttls

SendMail 8.14.x

With SSLv3 being sunset (to put it lightly), I'd like to ensure that my SendMail servers aren't using it when establishing STARTTLS connections. Is there a way I can force SendMail to NOT use SSLv3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tested this as I use posftix but I've seen in my reading the following:

```
CipherList=HIGH
ServerSSLOptions=+SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 +SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 +SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE
ClientSSLOptions=+SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 +SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3
```

Not sure which version this references but appears you control what ciphers are in use both when sendmail acts as a client and as a server.

Ref: http://www.michaelm.info/blog/?p=1256